# Trigger some jQuery code when a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have these two radio buttons:

```
Original <input id="video_is_derivative_false" name="video[is_derivative]" type="radio" value="false">
Derivative (<i>ex. remix, mashup etc...</i>) <input id="video_is_derivative_true" name="video[is_derivative]" type="radio" value="true">
```

and I want to call some jQuery code when the "Derivative" button is selected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just attach a change event to it:

```
$('#video_is_derivative_true').change(function(){
 console.log("Selected");   
})
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/cyADB/

Comment: As a non-partisan witness, @niklas was first, and among 5 answers of the same exact function, his works co-equally well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#video_is_derivative_true").click(function(){
alert("your code goes here");
});
```

Add an onclick handler to the input tag

You could also put something on the change handler

```
    $("#video_is_derivative_true").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert("more code here");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to monitor the change event, then in the handler, check to make sure that the button is checked.  The second part is important because the change event will also fire when it becomes unchecked.  The code would look something like this:

```
$('#video_is_derivative_true').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert('derivative checked!');
    }
});
```

[Here's a live demo ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/zfCnL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#video_is_derivative_true').bind('click change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        // derivative is checked
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#video_is_derivative_true").click(function(){ alert("your code goes here"); });
```